# Injecting a dependency into an Attribute using Unity in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, attributes, unity-container

I am trying to write an authentication attribute to apply to some services in a WCF Service App (using Unity and Unity.Wcf).

The authentication is carried out by an external (to the Service App) authentication interface which is currently injected via construction injection into the service class and called directly in each service method.

This leads to a lot of repeated code in each of the service methods.

Instead, I want to move that to an attribute.

But, I need the authentication interface to be accessible in the attribute.

Obviously, if I use construction injection on the attribute, it is then a required parameter when decorating my service method with the attribute but I don't have access to it at this point because it is wired up by Unity.

How can I inject (or otherwise have access to) the authentication interface in my attribute?

Comment: Either fall back to Service Locator and make the attribute a [Humble Object](http://xunitpatterns.com/Humble%20Object.html) that solely delegates to the service it resolves, or make the attribute passive, as explained [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/) and [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=98).

Comment: Thanks Steven, I shall have a read of those links

Comment: I base my opinion on [Mark Seeman's book](http://amzn.to/12p90MG) and therefore I treat Service Locator an anti-pattern. But if Steven gave an answer instead of a comment, I would upvoted it for the link to [passive attributes](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/).

Comment: Instead of injecting a dependency into an attribute, you could use the WCF extension points to execute some code on every wcf request - here is a stackoverflow article with some instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091384/how-to-run-code-on-every-service-request

Comment: @DanKaufman that's exactly what I am already doing - I need to inject a dependency into that...

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using Unity I would use AOP capabilities of Unity. Aspect Oriented Programing was designed to allow easy, DRY implementation of code to handle Cross-cutting concerns (like authentication and authorization). This allows to get rid of duplicated code and also decouples cross cutting concern from the business logic. You can easily inject dependencies into aspects created with Unity because they are resolved from the container in runtime (dynamic interception).

To create aspect with unity simply implement `IInterceptionBehavior` interface and apply it to the service you wont to decorate during container registration (instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx)).

Inside the aspect you can easily read all attributes that are applied to the method being intercepted so you can put roles that you need to have satisfied for your authentication scenario in the attribute (but no behavior).

I created a [demo solution](https://github.com/KrzysztofBranicki/aop-demo) to explain AOP, it uses CastleWindsor not Unity but same principles apply.